# Nesting Container View Controller inside another Container View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a Storyboard with an initial UIViewController (`vc1`) to which I added a Container View (holding `vc2`). Unfortunately my application is not entirely storyboarded, so when I attempt to add `vc1` to my MainController

```
 [MainController.view addSubview:vc1];
```

Xcode throws an exception

```
child view controller:<UIViewController: 0xcf9b270> should have parent view controller:<MainController: 0xcca1d20> but actual parent is:<vc1: 0xcf8b370>
```

I want its actual parent to be `SecondViewController`... Is there any way to achieve this without making the child view controller (`vc2`) a child of `MainController` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to add a child view controller:

```
[mainController addChildViewController:childController];
[mainController.view addSubview:childController.view];
[childController didMoveToParentViewController:mainController];
```

Comment: Tried that... but since my `childviewcontroller` contains another container view, it barks on that nested view controller, not on the `direct child`.

Comment: i m using same code in many applications and there are multiple nested child view controllers, didn't get errors.. are you adding child view controller on main view controller?? because whenever using nested child view controllers, the parent must always have to be that child which is adding another child as its child view controller